# getting original order when using attributes.keys - Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am constructing a resultset using,

```
@time_spent = TimeEntry.find(:all,
                         :joins => "INNER JOIN sometable ON x = y",
                         :select =>"id, subject, spent_on")
```

And to get column names i am using

```
@time_spent[index].attributes.keys
```

But it gives me column names in some random order. How can i get in the order same as in select clause.

Can any one tell on what basis elements are ordered when using attributes.keys?

Any hints would be helpful.
Thnx.

Comment: Keys are ordered by select clause for me, what ruby/rails versions are you using?

Comment: Just curious, is there some compelling reason to get the column names in order? Because if you need them in order, I would look for some other method of doing that explicitly.

Comment: @injekt, i am using rails version 2.3.14 and ruby 1.8.7

Comment: @muffinista, just curious to know how can it be done. and what are other methods or ways of doing it explicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command

```
@time_spent[index].attributes
```

Returns a regular Ruby hash. For ruby 1.8, according to [the docs](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html):

> The order in which you traverse a hash by either key or value may seem
>   arbitrary, and will generally not be in the insertion order.

In ruby 1.9, this has changed, and now according to [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) "Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted."

If you really wanted to learn more, you'd have to dig into the internals of your Ruby version, but there's not much point in that.  In ruby 1.8, you can pretty safely expect the keys to come out in an un-helpful order for you, and if you need them in some sort of specific order, you will need to implement that yourself.

Comment: thnx for the detailed explanation.